# How to check if an input answer to a randomly generated mathematical equation is correct

Tags: java, random

I have a Java program that generates 2 random numbers and asks a user for a mathematical operator and uses those 3 elements to ask the user an equation. I am trying to check if the answer the user inputs is correct and display either correct or incorrect.

```
RandomGenerator rand = new RandomGenerator();
x=rand.nextInt(-10,10);
y=rand.nextInt(-10,10);

op=readLine("Choose an operator (+, -, /, or *): "); 
equ = x + op + y + "= "; 
val = readInt(equ); 
z = x + op + y 
if(z == val) { 
    println("CORRECT!!"); 
} 
if(z != val) { 
    println("Incorrect."); 
}
```

Comment: You mean like a captcha? You could store the randomly generated text in session and check the user response. Please post the code that you have tried.

Comment: This is the code I have but the z= part doesnt work.

RandomGenerator rand = new RandomGenerator();
x = rand.nextInt(-10, 10);
y = rand.nextInt(-10, 10);
op = readLine("Choose an operator (+, -, /, or *): ");
equ = x + op + y + "= ";
val = readInt(equ);
z = x + op + y
if(z == val) {
println("CORRECT!!");
}
if(z != val) {
println("Incorrect.");
}

Comment: Please use the [edit] option to post updates to your question. You should avoid using comments section to post your code. Also don't forget to add your full code.

Answer (score 0):

The number of operators are limited so you may want to have Switch cases for each operator and calculate the values. for example

```
case '+':

 value = a + b;

case '-':

String value = a + b;
```